# Web page in iOS Address book

Tags: ios, addressbook

I need to read/write to the user's address book and am using the AddressBookUI for the purpose.

I've mapped up most of the properties, but have now spent far too much time trying to figure out which property contains the web page. I would have expected it to be called kABPersonHomePageProperty or something ...

Could someone please give me a pointer!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called `kABPersonURLProperty`. You can find it in the `ABPerson` reference.

Comment: Thanks! Strange, it didn't turn up in the autocomplete.